# add the hover effect to the full width of a nav items inside the flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I wanted to add a hover effect over an item like in the figure. But not the **border** (that is shown only as of the example)

[image]

But I have got the hover effect from the below snippet in a different way, The height of the `nav-items` doesn't reach to the top and bottom of the flex-box.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}
.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  height: 70px;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.header__left {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.header__logo {
  height: 25px;
  padding-right:10em;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.navbar__nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.navbar__nav li.active-tab {
  color: #ea2330;
  background-color:lightgray;
}

.nav__item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #666666;
  margin-right:4px;
}
.nav__item:hover {
  color: #ea2330;
  background-color:lightgray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato&display=swap" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
  <title>Navigation Menu</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="header__left">
      <img class="header__logo" src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/fire-logo-png-svg-free-download-fire-logo-11563553513c3wo0p7dt1.png" />
      <a>
        <i class="fas fa-bars"> </i>
      </a>
    </div>
      <div class="header__option">
        <ul class="navbar__nav">
          <li class="nav__item active-tab">
            <i class="nav__item__icon fas fa-globe"></i>
            <a class="nav__link">Company</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav__item">
            <i class="nav__item__icon fas fa-street-view"></i
            ><a class="nav__link">Branch</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav__item">
            <i class="nav__item__icon fas fa-users"></i
            ><a class="nav__link">Employee</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I have also tryout by adding the `padding:19px;` in `nav__items`, it gave a similar kind of effect but not exactly the same way as I expected, however, is this a correct approach for this?

```
.nav__item {
  padding:19px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are Points you missed. if you set extra padding or height because each item will be inline-block when you use display flex, you can't pretend to be display block and expect it to completely cover its space. so I removed the incorrect padding and so on. I mentioned what I added and removed in the comment lines.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  /* REMOVED*/
  /* height: 100px; */
  /* padding: 1rem 2rem; */
  padding: 0 2rem;
  /* changed */
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.header__left {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.header__logo {
  height: 25px;
  padding-right: 10em;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.navbar__nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  /* added */
}

.navbar__nav li.active-tab {
  color: #ea2330;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.nav__item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /*added */
  width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #666666;
  margin-right: 4px;
  height: 80px;
  /* added */
}

.nav__item:hover {
  color: #ea2330;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/dc0c634418.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="header">
  <div class="header__left">
    <img class="header__logo" src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/fire-logo-png-svg-free-download-fire-logo-11563553513c3wo0p7dt1.png" />
    <a>
      <i class="fas fa-bars"> </i>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="header__option">
    <ul class="navbar__nav">
      <li class="nav__item active-tab">
        <i class="nav__item__icon fas fa-globe"></i>
        <a class="nav__link">Company</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav__item">
        <i class="nav__item__icon fas fa-street-view"></i><a class="nav__link">Branch</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav__item">
        <i class="nav__item__icon fas fa-users"></i><a class="nav__link">Employee</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: height seem to be extra larger, how should I reduce now, because at first, I had the height on `.header`, now you have removed that.

Comment: the header currently has no fixed height. I removed it so you could get the image you wanted, yes. nav__item affects the height of the Header. if you change the height of it, the height of the header will be adjusted automatically. I've set it to 80px, you can change it as you like.

Comment: Thank you nicely explained. I will accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

this is how you wanted it?

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}
.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  height: 70px;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.header__left {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.header__logo {
  height: 25px;
  padding-right:10em;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.navbar__nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.navbar__nav li.active-tab {
  color: #ea2330;
  background-color:lightgray;
}

.nav__item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #666666;
  margin-right:4px;
}
.navbar__nav li.active-tab {
    color: #ea2330;
    background-color: lightgray;
    border-color: grey;
    border-style: groove;
    padding: 12px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato&display=swap" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
  <title>Navigation Menu</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="header__left">
      <img class="header__logo" src="https://toppng.com/uploads/preview/fire-logo-png-svg-free-download-fire-logo-11563553513c3wo0p7dt1.png" />
      <a>
        <i class="fas fa-bars"> </i>
      </a>
    </div>
      <div class="header__option">
        <ul class="navbar__nav">
          <li class="nav__item active-tab">
            <i class="nav__item__icon fas fa-globe"></i>
            <a class="nav__link">Company</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav__item">
            <i class="nav__item__icon fas fa-street-view"></i
            ><a class="nav__link">Branch</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav__item">
            <i class="nav__item__icon fas fa-users"></i
            ><a class="nav__link">Employee</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

adding border style and `padding:12px`

Comment: no not the **border** (that is shown only as of the example)